# Search integer in array formed by joining two sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in interview. There are two sorted arrays of size N and M and they are joined together such that resulting array is not sorted. In result array elements from 0 to N-1 are from first array and elements from N to M+N-1 are from the second arrays.

How to find an integer in such arrays. Both array contain unique elements and there is no intersection among the two original arrays. Time complexity should be O(log(N+M)) and space complexity should be O(1).

e.g.

Array 1 is [3,4,5]
Array 2 is [1,2]
resulting array is [3,4,5,1,2]

How to search in this array?

Comment: Do you have informations about original sizes of arrays (N and M)?

Comment: Do you know the values of N and M?

Comment: @Pshemo sizes are no needed n and m are enough to know.

Comment: size of arrays are N and M variable. we have to write code for function int search(int[] A, int B[], int x).

Comment: If you know N and M, what's the problem with running two binary searches?

Comment: "we have to write code for function `int search(int[] A, int B[], int x)`" that is not what your question says. From your title it looks like you need to write method like `int (int[] mergedAB, int x)`.

Comment: even if you know N and M and you use binary search, you can solve it in O(log(N)+log(M)) which is O(log(N*M)) which is greater than O(log(N+M)) for positive values of N and M...

Comment: @TejashDesai No, it's not. `log(n*m) <= max{log(n^2),log(m^2)} = 2max{log{n},log{m}` - which is also in `O(log(n) + log(m))`, and similarly `log(n+m) <= max{log(2n),log(2m)} = log(2) + max{log(n),log(m)}`, which is in `O(log(n)+log(m))` I believe you can show big Omega in similar way: `log(n+m) >= max{log(n),log(m)}` which is in `Omega(log(n) + log(m))`

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the merge-sort approach.

[image]

Now, jump to the last step, here we have 2 arrays which are sorted and are to be joined into a single list.

What we do, start with an element and check with the other array's element, based on the order we insert into the array.

In the same way, we search for the element looking into these two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Because the arrays `[0,N-1]` and `[N,N+M-1]` are sorted. you can use `binary search` in both of this array which will result to `log(N)+log(M)` complexity with a space complexity `O(1)`.

Comment: @ParaSara log(n+m) <= max{log(2n),log(2m)} = log(2) + max{log(n),log(m)}, which is in O(log(n)+log(m))

Comment: Similarly, `log(n*m) <= max{log(n^2),log(m^2)} = 2max{log{n},log{m}` - which is also in `O(log(n) + log(m))`

Answer (score 0):

If you know `N` and `M`, then its easy. First do a binary search in the first part, then in the second part. Time complexity is `O(log(N))` + `(O(log(M)) <= O(log(N+M))`.

If you don't know `N` and `M` then you need to look at every element, i.e. you can't do better than linear time.

Answer (score 0):

O(log(M)+log(N)) is larger than O(log(M+N)), but not more than twice:

O(log(M+N)) <= O(log(M)+log(N)) <= 2*O(log(M+N))

Answer (score 0):

I could think of this optimal solution and I guess time complexity is O(Nlog(M-N)) considering N < M.

1. Iterate over the combined array in both direction simultaneously.
   Assuming both previous arrays sorted in ascending order one iterator
   will start from 0 and iterate in forward direction looking for point
   where arrays are joint. Another iterator will iterate from end and
   move backwards looking for join point.
2. In each iteration we will compare value of forward and backward
   iterator to search integer K.
3. Once Join point is find we will do binary search on remaining elements 
   of array which are not being touched by both iterators.

   ```
   class cls
   {
       public int search(int merged[], int x)
       {
           int ret = -1, a = 0 , b = 0;
           boolean arrn = false;
           //a is forward and b is backward iterator
           //looking for index where arrays are joined.
           for(b = merged.length - 1;a < b ;a++,b--)
           {
               //compare values of iterator to K
               if( merged[a] == x )
               {
                   ret = a;
                   return ret;
               }

               if ( merged[b] == x )
               {
                   ret = b;
                   return ret;
               }

               //if a is the point where first array ends then 
               //do binarysearch in remaining element of array which 
               //are not visited by both a and b. Since original arrays
               //  soreted. It is guaranteed that a+1 to b is also sorted.
               //
               if ( !( merged[a] < merged[a + 1] ) )
               {
                   ret = Arrays.binarySearch(merged, a+1, b, x);
                   return ret;
               }

               if ( !( merged[b - 1] < merged[b] ) )
               {
                   ret = Arrays.binarySearch(merged, a + 1, b - 1, x);
                   return ret;
               }
           }
           return ret;
       }
   ```

   }